# InputText based on InputSelect value

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Modal body

```
<EditForm Model="itemModel" OnSubmit="HandleSubmit" class="modal-body">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="SKU" class="form-label">SKU</label>
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="@itemModel.Name" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
            @foreach (var item in skus)
            {
                <option value="@item.SKU" id="@item.SKU">@item.SKU</option>
            }
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Unit" class="form-label">Unit</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@itemModel.Unit" class="form-control" id="Unit" readonly></InputText>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Quantity" class="form-label">Quantity</label>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="@itemModel.Quantity" min="1" step="any" class="form-control" id="Unit"></InputNumber>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

ItemModel has 3 properties - Name (string), Unit (string), Quantity (double)

SKUModel has 2 properties - SKU (string), Unit (string)

ItemModel will be added to `List<ItemModel>` that will be sent to an API

`List<SKUModel>` is filled from an API call

```
ItemModel itemModel = new ItemModel();
List<SKUModel> skus = new List<SKUModel>();
```

I'm writing a small warehouse management Blazor WASM app as a learning project. The employee will be opening a modal, in which they will select an item from an InputSelect, then they will enter quantity. Every item pulled from an API has it's own unit symbol, and I need to display it in the InputText Unit based on selected item.SKU. How can I do that?

Comment: On **skus** dropdown select you want to display the **Unit** symbol in the Unit TextField. Is this your requirement? The Unit symbol you are referring to in the **SKUModel** or in a different model?

Comment: "Changing skus model should display its corresponding Unit value in the Unit TextField. Is this your requirement?" Basically yes. Unit symbol is both in ItemModel that will be sent to an API, and a SKUModel that is grabbed from API during initialization of app

Comment: Instead of bind-value you can use **OnValueChanged** event to perform custom operation when a user selects from the dropdown. If require you can make another API call or query Item Model/SkuModel to get Unit symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what *unit symbol* is, so I've stuck to a description.

Here's a quick demo page to show you how to update the unit input based on the selected SKU/Name.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm Model="itemModel" OnSubmit="HandleSubmit">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="SKU" class="form-label">SKU</label>
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="@itemModel.Name" @bind-Value:after="SetUnit" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
            @if(itemModel.Name is null)
            {
                <option selected disabled value=""> -- Select an Item -- </option>
            }
            @foreach (var item in SKUModelProvider.SKUModels)
            {
                <option value="@item.SKU" id="@item.SKU">@item.SKU</option>
            }
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Unit" class="form-label">Unit</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@itemModel.Unit" class="form-control" id="Unit" readonly></InputText>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Quantity" class="form-label">Quantity</label>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="@itemModel.Quantity" min="1" step="any" class="form-control" id="Unit"></InputNumber>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private ItemModel itemModel = new();

    public void HandleSubmit()
    {
    }

    public void SetUnit()
    {
        var sku = SKUModelProvider.SKUModels.FirstOrDefault(item => item.SKU == itemModel.Name);
        itemModel.Unit = sku?.Unit ?? null;
    }
    
    public record SKUModel(string SKU, string Unit);

    public class ItemModel
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Unit { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public static class SKUModelProvider
    {
        private static List<SKUModel> _sKUModels = new() { new("SKU100", "Litres"), new("SKU200", "Pack"), new("SKU300", "Bottle") };

        public static IEnumerable<SKUModel> SKUModels => _sKUModels.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```